# rake db:migrate throws undefined method 'symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass

Tags: ruby-on-rails, rake

Working with rails for the first time and I getting a rake error when I try:
`rake db:migrate RAILS_ENV=staging`

The Error:
    (in [my current directory])
    rake aborted!
    undefined method `symbolize_keys' for nil:NilClass

Has anyone seen this?

Comment: Do you only get the error when running in the staging environment? What about development?

Comment: @Beerlington: Would that adversely affect anything?

Comment: It could if the rake task was looking for a non-existent staging environment, found nil, and tried to call nil.symbolize_keys.

Comment: I was just curious if it was specific to a staging environment setting or a problem with the migration. If it works in a different environment, then I'd look at your database.yml file and compare staging to an environment that's working.

Comment: Run the rake with --trace so we can see where it is failing.

Answer (score 4):

I had this same problem today.  I forgot to add 'staging' to my yaml config file.  It had dev/test/prod... but I overlooked staging.

e.g. 
config/initializers/app_config.rb
APP_CONFIG = YAML.load_file("#{RAILS_ROOT}/config/app_config.yml")[RAILS_ENV].symbolize_keys

Answer (score 0):

The error is most likely occurring when your config yaml files are being loaded and it is trying to find a staging configuration that is not there. (It is trying to`symbolize` the keys for staging environment, but since they are not there it is attempting to `symbolize` `nil`) Check your yaml files in the config directory to see if you are missing a staging configuration. Once you add that, everything should work.

Hope that helps.

Answer (score 0):

In rails 3.2 make sure you have a section for staging or whatever your enviroment name is in config/settings.yml